# How to show keyboard keys in answers

Tags: support

The answer to this post:

[F12 Jump to method -> go back to previous method after making the jump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7686347/f12-jump-to-method-go-back-to-previous-method-after-making-the-jump)

nicely shows keyboard keys with graphics. How can I do that?

Comment: Whenever you're unsure, click on "edit" and it'll show you how the original post was made. Then you'll be able to figure these things out yourself :)

Answer (score 19):

Welcome to the awesome world of the `kbd` element!

<kbd>This is how it's done</kbd>:

```
<kbd>Awesome!</kbd>
```

Comment: Please do confine yourself to keys on the keyboard or other input. Try to avoid using it for links :).

Comment: <kbd>I wonder</kbd> if the KBD tag is only parsed in questions and answers, and not allowed for comments.